# I want to mask multiple Image horizontally

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have few Journal pages images where there are two columns I want to mask one column white without a changing the dimension.which means the output image should have same dimensions as input image even though there is one column.

I was able to mask image but the mask part is coming black which I want as white.

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

# Load the original image

image = cv2.imread(filename = "D:\output_final_word5\image1.jpg")

# Create the basic black image 

mask = np.zeros(shape = image.shape, dtype = "uint8")

# Draw a white, filled rectangle on the mask image

cv2.rectangle(img = mask, pt1 = (0, 0), pt2 = (795, 3000), color = (255, 255, 

255), thickness = -1)

# Apply the mask and display the result

maskedImg = cv2.bitwise_and(src1 = image, src2 = mask)

#cv2.namedWindow(winname = "masked image", flags = cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("masked image",maskedImg)

cv2.waitKey(delay = 0)

cv2.imwrite("D:\Test_Mask.jpg",maskedImg)
```

My final objective is to read a folder where are several Journal pages In which need to be saved by masking first one column and then another column without affecting the dimension of Input image and mask part should be white.
Below are Input Image Attached...

[image: Input_Image1]

[image: Input_Image2]

And Output Should be like this....

[image: Output_Image1]

[image: Output_Image2]

Comment: The last 2 images are the expected output?

Comment: @ZdaR Yes.......

Comment: you can use PIL/pillow to draw white recatangles without using cv2

Comment: I don't know why you use mask if you can draw rectangle on image.

Comment: Agreed with @furas. There is no need of a mask in this case. Just make 2 copies of the image, draw a while rectangle for the first half of the image_1 and draw a white rectangle for the second half of the image_2

Comment: @furas  would you please tell how to do so....

Comment: @ZdaR  would you please tell how to do so....

Comment: You are already doing that here: `cv2.rectangle(img = mask, pt1 = (0, 0), pt2 = (795, 3000), color = (255, 255, 255), thickness = -1)`

Comment: use `img=image` instead of `img=mask` and you will draw white rectangle directly on your image. As @ZdaR already said first you should duplicate/copy image to have two instances `image2 = image.copy()` to create image with other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need mask to draw rectangle. You can draw it directly on image.

You can also use `image.copy()` to create second image with other column

BTW: if `795` is in the middle of width then you can use `image.shape` to get its `(height,width)` and use `width//2` instead of `795` so it will work with images which have different widths. But if `795` is not ideally in the middle then use `half_width = 795`

```
import cv2

image_1 = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
image_2 = image_1.copy()

height, width, depth = image_1.shape # it gives `height,width`, not `width,height`
half_width = width//2
#half_width = 795

cv2.rectangle(img=image_1, pt1=(0, 0), pt2=(half_width, height), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)
cv2.rectangle(img=image_2, pt1=(half_width, 0), pt2=(width, height), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=-1)

cv2.imwrite("image_1.jpg", image_1)
cv2.imwrite("image_2.jpg", image_2)

cv2.imshow("image 1", image_1)
cv2.imshow("image 2", image_2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```